# Get terraform s3 state bucket name in code

Tags: terraform

I have the following terraform backend:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "zorbo-state-bucket"
    key    = "solutions/test"
    region = "eu-central-1"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get the state bucket name somewhere else in my code?
For example, instead of writing this:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "organization" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket = "zorbo-state-bucket"
    key = "solutions/first"
    region = "eu-central-1"
  }
}
```

I can replace the bucket name with something like:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "organization" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket = terraform.backend.s3.bucket
    key = "solutions/first"
    region = "eu-central-1"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/configuration.html#using-a-backend-block

Comment: you can do it, but using a variables file (hardcoded values on that var file)

Comment: @MattSchuchard, the reference link does not say it is impossible, but nor does it say how to get the reference to `terraform.backend.s3.bucket`.  I understand you can't use a variable to set the bucket name. So how do you extract the fixed string using HCL syntax while keeping it DRY?

Comment: Would you be happy to define the bucket name in locals, then reference that local value in both the backend definition and anywhere else your code requires it?